# Ignore specific rules for a group of IP addresses

Tags: nginx, mod-security, mod-security2

Is it possible to ignore specific rules (OWASP CRS for ModSecurity on NGINX) for a specific group of whitelisted IPs?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. You can add IP Based whitelisting for specific rules in ModSecurity. Please refer to the doc from the link below:

https://www.modsecurity.org/CRS/Documentation/exceptions.html

and

https://malware.expert/tutorial/how-to-whitelist-ip-address-with-modsecurity/

Comment: Don't know if there is a secret sause, but per those links I've tried to disable a rule  
 with
    **SecRule REMOTE_ADDR ".ip.." "id:21,ctl:ruleRemoveById=90000011" ** 
and  
    SecRule REMOTE_ADDR ".ip."  
 "id:21,phase:1,nolog,allow,ctl:ruleRemoveById=90000011"
but both fail - whereas  
   `  SecRule REMOTE_ADDR ".ip." "id:21,phase:1,nolog,allow,ctl:ruleEngine=Off"  `
does work, but is not IP-specific so not useful to me (modsecurity verion 1.5.2)

Comment: PS: would really like to know why inserting the supposed comment formatting characters, per the "help" link, has no effect (ran out of time at 5 mins trying to find a solution, so above has no formatting.  Sorry.